# In XAML style, how to change solid background to gradient?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I've got a MainResources.xaml file in which I have a style that defines how each of my windows in my application look:

```
  <Style x:Key="MainBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  </Style>
```

Instead of "WhiteSmoke" I want my background to be this gradient:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush>
        <GradientStop Color="#ccc" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#bbb" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

But the following attempt causes VS2008 to tell me "Style setters do not support child elements":

```
<Style x:Key="MainBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#ccc" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#bbb" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

What is the correct way to put a gradient color as the background for this style?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You are missing the `<Setter.Value>`

```
<Style ...> 
   <Setter Property="...">
      <Setter.Value>
         <LinearGradientBrush />
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```