# WPF Datagrid.RowStyle gradient background

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to change the datagrid's row background from a solid colour to gradient. Any ideas?

The current code is:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GSRowBackground}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The solution (thanks for pointing me in the right direction):

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GSRowBackground}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background">
     <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
       <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#888888"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFF86E"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In XAML style, how to change solid background to gradient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520190/in-xaml-style-how-to-change-solid-background-to-gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions (thanks for pointing me in the right direction):

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GSRowBackground}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background">
     <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
       <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#888888"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFF86E"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="gradientBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
       <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#888888"/>
       <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFF86E"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{StaticResource gradientBrush}" Padding="0,0,3,3">        
                    <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```